# Efficiently designing relationship between classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, mongodb, one-to-many, bidirectional

I want to know if the below relationship model between classes can be improved. I am using MongoDB as a database layer.

```
public class TodoItem {
 private String description;
 private Person person;
}

public class Person {
 private List<TodoItem> items;
}
```

Again my question is specific to the design of classes where relationship like One-to-Many and Bi-Direction is involved. Thanks.

Comment: Is it always true that an employee belongs to one department?  In a lot of corporations this is not the case.

Comment: What about a hierarchy of Departments?

Comment: You should give more informations about the context

Comment: What are the requirements for the design?

Comment: @JensSchauder no requirements - I am just trying to learn the correct way of writing relationships. If you see Person is storing the complete list of TodoItems. Is this correct? or it should only store Ids of those TodoItems?

Comment: @jsinghfoss you should ask a **specific question**, and not go through an example that you change completely (and thus change your question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your requirements/environment.

e.g. you have bidirectional dependencies. They are trouble some to maintain, but nice for the client using this. What is more important? Do you really need to navigate both ways more or less equally often?

You store full objects. Maybe you should store proxies instead or id's and a repository. Nobody can tell until we know about your requirements, both functional and non functional.

Actually if you don't have requirements, the design is wrong, because you shouldn't have a class if it doesn't help fulfilling a requirement.

There is no absolute right or wrong in software design. If such a decision would be possible we wouldn't need to make it manually, it would be available as a language feature in every modern language. Design is about understanding requirements and understanding the effects design decision have on the degree of fulfillment of those requirements.

So if you want to learn about design try the following:

Take simple functional requirements and think about how your design changes with changing  non functional requirements: it has to run on a chip card; it has to process thousands requests per second. Lots of writes, few reads; Lots of reads, few writes. ...

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to have bidirectionnal associations? For example, does Department has to know to which Company it belongs?

With a unidirectionnal association you have less coupling, `Department` doesn't have to know anything about `Company` (or change if `Company` changes). Same goes for `Project`, `Employee`, ...

Without more informations that's all I see.

Comment: Updated my code and left a comment above.

Comment: You completely changed your question, now my answer doesn't mean anything. If you want to ask another question, you should create another one (and maybe link it here).

Comment: Well, as I said my question was specific to design. I have modified it to narrow it down to a bidirectional association. So, now it is striking your first sentence "Do you really..." How can we have a simpler design without tight coupling? Include only IDs? Again, I'm sorry I was too vague the first time. Will remember for future.

Comment: Don't use ID's. You will loose every advantage of OOP, classes and all, and you will get into trouble managing those Id's. If you need bidirectional association, use it. Else, don't.

Comment: cool - thanks. i wanted to make that point clear which you have.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer would be

```
public class Company {
 private List<Department> departments;
}

public class Department {
    private List<Employee> employees;
    private List<Project> projects;
    private Map<Employee, Project> employeeProject;
}

public class Employee {
   private String name;
}
```

Comment: Projects may include people from multiple departments. IMO this task should not be oversimplified.

Comment: I'm with Alex on this one, we don't know how project are related to employees or departements except the fact that a user has many projects. This *may* not be compatible with the original design.

Comment: I have simplified my code to focus on one question i.e. whether Person needs to store IDs of items or maintain a list of complete TodoItems. And this is bi-direction relationship. Sorry I wasn't clear the first time.